# Variable cookie path with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: cookies, asp.net-identity, owin

We migrated a multitenant MVC application from ASP.NET Membership Provider to ASP.NET Identity.

This is my Startup.Auth.cs (simplified):

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity =
                    SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, Identity, int>(
                        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        (manager, user) =>
                            manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie),
                        clIdentity => clIdentity.GetUserId<int>())
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
}
```

In our multitenant application, each tenant has its own 'slug' (e.g. http://example.com/tenant1/ and http://example.com/tenant2/)

However, currently, the cookies are stored in the root. This causes security issues as users from tenant1 are automatically logged in on the website from tenant2.

**How can we make the CookiePath (in CookieAuthenticationOptions) variable so that it changes depending on the tenant?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this issue with a lot of help from [dampee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97615/dampee).

The *CookiePath* in the *CookieAuthenticationOptions* object is evaluated only once: at application startup.
The easiest solution (workaround) was to create a derived **CookieAuthenticationProvider** that overrides **ResponseSignIn** and **ResponseSignOut**.
They both have an argument called *context* which has a property called *CookiePath*. Modify this property in both of these methods to change the CookiePath.
You can also [use the class I created](https://gist.github.com/SamuelDebruyn/724cc865569d9a2752a2).

Then all you have to do is replace the *CookieAuthenticationProvider* in the *CookieAuthenticationOptions* with the one you just created.

This works for the ApplicationCookie. The ExternalSignInCookie doesn't matter that much since it is used only temporarily while signing in with an external login.

Answer (score 2):

Improving on SamuelDebruyn's own solution, I found you can pass the path from the SignIn call to the provider using an `AuthenticationProperties` object. This way, instead of extracting the path from the request context as his gist shows, you can pass it explicitly from the source:

```cs
// method inside web api controller
private void SignIn(string name, string cookiePath)
{
    var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name) };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie");

    var options = new AuthenticationProperties();
    options.Dictionary["CustomCookiePath"] = cookiePath;

    var authManager = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    authManager.SignIn(options, identity);
}

// Startup.cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new CustomCookieProvider()
});

// custom provider
public class CustomCookieProvider : CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override void ResponseSignIn(CookieResponseSignInContext context)
    {
        context.CookieOptions.Path = context.Properties.Dictionary["CustomCookiePath"];
        base.ResponseSignIn(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom `ICookieManager` to dynamically return the cookie value to the `CookieAuthenticationProvider` based on whatever is in the request, to do this you would still maintain the CookiePath as "/" and then leave it up to the `ICookieManager` to return (or write) the cookie however you want. The `CookieManager` is an option on the `CookieAuthenticationOptions`. I blogged about this here: http://shazwazza.com/post/owin-cookie-authentication-with-variable-cookie-paths/