# How to set different CookiePath for each area in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-identity

As security guidelines recommends `CookiePath` must be changed from default value which is '/' to the specific folder of application, but that cause a problem when I use area concept of ASP.NET MVC, so how can I set different `CookiePath` for each Area.

PS. I use ASP.NET Identity for membership

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(
             new HttpCookie("test", "hello") { Path = @"/Admin", 
             Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)});

        return RedirectToAction("About", "Admin");
    }
}

public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        var cookieCount = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Count;
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Hope this is helpful :)**

Comment: Sorry but how can this help me? I need to change the path of authentication cookie according to the area name

Comment: then check this , hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518092/variable-cookie-path-with-asp-net-identity  @NiklausWirth

Answer (score 0):

> *As security guidelines recommends*

what security guidelines and what context are they talking about? This is the first time I hear about this guideline and it does not make sense in the current state of affairs of Asp.Net Identity.

You may want to implement different security per area, but this is done via roles, not by different cookie per path.

Comment: Yes that must be implemented by roles, but we need to set different path for cookie for different area

Comment: @NiklausWirth but why?