# Change the domain in a cookie (ASP.Net and Microsoft.Owin.Security)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, owin.security

I use the libraries Microsoft.Owin.Security, Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIDConnect and Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies. It works fine and I can create a security cookie. 
But in the security cookie is the domain `AAA.de`. How I can change the domain in the cookie to `.AAA.de` ?

This is the code I use to sign in the user.

```
public void SignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties(
                new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {Startup.PolicyKey, Startup.SignInPolicyId}
                })
                {
                    RedirectUri = Redirect,
                }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.Net Identity - Setting CookieDomain at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989920/asp-net-identity-setting-cookiedomain-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie domain can be configured by using a custom Cookie provider - this is typically configured as part of the Application Startup process - you've probably also got an `App_Start` folder with a `Startup.Auth.cs` class in it (if you've started with the typical base project.

Your provider would look something like:

```
public class CookieAuthProvider : CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override void ResponseSignIn(CookieResponseSignInContext context)
    {
      //Alter you cookie options
      context.CookieOptions.Domain  =  ".AAA.de";      
      base.ResponseSignIn(context);
    }
 }
```

You can then call this from your startup class via:

```
CookieAuthProvider myProvider = new CookieAuthProvider();
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
   AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
   LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
   Provider = myProvider
});
```

Based heavily on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23221846/33051) to "Asp.Net Identity - Setting CookieDomain at runtime"